# Qt Debugger Console does not see debug sessions

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

Tried asking the official Qt forum first, to no avail.

Qt Creator 4.2.0 (Community), Windows 7 SP1, MSVC 2013 64 bit. Trying to debug a preinstalled example project. Debug session is running, breakpoints work, variable values update, but Debugger Console window keeps saying "Can only evaluate during a debug session" regardless of what I type in it. Any ideas how to fix the thing?

UPDATE: Compile output follows.

```
21:51:30: Running steps for project svgviewer...
21:51:30: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
21:51:30: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\svgviewer.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\svgviewer -I. -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtSvg -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.7392.31.jom
main.cpp
C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\rcc.exe -name svgviewer ..\svgviewer\svgviewer.qrc -o debug\qrc_svgviewer.cpp
C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_MSC_VER=1800 -D_WIN32 -D_WIN64 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/Examples/Qt-5.7/svg/svgviewer -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtSvg -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtOpenGL -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtCore -I. ..\svgviewer\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_MSC_VER=1800 -D_WIN32 -D_WIN64 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/Examples/Qt-5.7/svg/svgviewer -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtSvg -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtOpenGL -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtCore -I. ..\svgviewer\exportdialog.h -o debug\moc_exportdialog.cpp
C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_MSC_VER=1800 -D_WIN32 -D_WIN64 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/Examples/Qt-5.7/svg/svgviewer -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtSvg -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtOpenGL -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/msvc2013_64/include/QtCore -I. ..\svgviewer\svgview.h -o debug\moc_svgview.cpp
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\svgviewer.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\svgviewer -I. -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtSvg -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\qrc_svgviewer.obj.7392.218.jom
qrc_svgviewer.cpp
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\svgviewer.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\svgviewer -I. -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtSvg -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.7392.343.jom
moc_mainwindow.cpp
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\svgviewer.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\svgviewer -I. -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtSvg -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_exportdialog.obj.7392.406.jom
moc_exportdialog.cpp
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\svgviewer.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\svgviewer -I. -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtSvg -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_svgview.obj.7392.421.jom
moc_svgview.cpp
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\svgviewer.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\svgviewer -I. -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtSvg -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\exportdialog.obj.7392.47.jom
exportdialog.cpp
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\svgviewer.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\svgviewer -I. -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtSvg -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.7392.31.jom
mainwindow.cpp
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\svgviewer.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\svgviewer -I. -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtSvg -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\svgview.obj.7392.31.jom
svgview.cpp
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\svgviewer.exe @C:\Users\msl\AppData\Local\Temp\svgviewer.exe.7392.3416.jom
21:51:35: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
21:51:35: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Comment: It appears like the code built as Release not Debug.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Configuration is named Debug and I can inspect variables. I think it is built as Debug. Maybe there is some additional switch missing somewhere?

Comment: You can post the compiler output from Compile Output console?

Comment: But of course. Hope I formatted it right.

Comment: All appears to match the debug compile mode, -Zi is there.

Answer (score 7):

The "[Debugger Console](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-qml.html#executing-javascript-expressions)" is used for QML, and you can evaluate JavaScript expressions in the context of a QML debug session there.

For interacting with the native C/C++ debugger you'd use the left side of the Debugger Log view (Window > Views > Debugger Log, while in Debug mode). [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html#directly-interacting-with-native-debuggers).

Comment: Saw that log window thing, thanks. Sadly, its functionality is very limited. So, the net result appears to be that Qt Creator does not have a debug console in the sense other IDEs do?

Comment: @sigil "Sadly, its functionality is very limited" I don't know much about what you can do with CDB, but with GDB and LLDB you can do anything from the debugger log that you can do with GDB and LLDB, so I'd expect the same with CDB. Not sure what you expect to be able to do with a "debugger console"? You can also evaluate expressions in the "Locals and Expressions" view, and can change values of variables with simple types there. (http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html)

Comment: I'd like to be able to evaluate expressions like `pos().x() + width() / 2`, for instance. Locals and Expressions is dead slow -- a simple refresh can easily take a minute. Qt documentation confirms it. I had a misplaced hope that at least debug console would work like, say, in Visual Studio. Will stick with `qDebug()` and constant rebuilds, I guess.

Comment: @sigil And can you evaluate cdb commands in the debugger log? You should be able to evaluate expressions in cdb too, with `??`, as far as I can see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566251(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: IMO the "Debugger Console" is really terribly named. Also the "Debugger Log" view doesn't seem to give you the ability to attach to the program immediately *before* it starts. Using r will cause the console to quit working.